# SMJobBless and NSXPCConnection

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, kernel-extension, xpc, nsxpcconnection

There is an Apple [SMJobBless](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SMJobBless/Introduction/Intro.html) example that show how to securely install a helper tool. [SMJobBlessXPC](https://github.com/atnan/SMJobBlessXPC) is uses XPC (c API) over Mach ports for communication between the app and privileged helper tool.

I need SMJobBlessXPC by using NSXPCConnection (Objective c API).

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for the "[Even Better Authorization Sample](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/EvenBetterAuthorizationSample/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013768-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2)". It's a sample project showing how to set up a privileged helper using `SMJobBless`, and communicate with it using `NSXPCConnection`.

Comment: The ReadMe of SMJobBless states: "As of Snow Leopard, this is the preferred method of managing privilege escalation on Mac OS X and should be used instead of earlier approaches such as BetterAuthorizationSample or directly calling AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges."

Comment: @ElisevanLooij The ***Even* Better** Authorization Sample documentation says: "EvenBetterAuthorizationSample uses modern technology--namely SMJobBless […] as compared to older samples." So I think it's a good sample project despite the others you mention (like the only "Better" authorization one) being deprecated.